# Error: Cannot find module when deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, procfile

I have a project with the following structure:

```
root_folder
- package.json
- server
-- index.js
- signalmaster
-- server.js
```

I am trying to deploy the app and start 2 node servers with a Procfile:

```
web: node server/index.js
webrtc: node signalmaster/server.js
```

The 2 servers can be started in different tabs locally if I run:

```
node server/index.js
node signalmaster/server.js
```

But when I deploy it to Heroku I get the following errors:

```
Starting process with command `node signalmaster/server.js`
2018-02-08T02:45:52.143212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-02-08T02:45:52.450671+00:00 heroku[webrtc.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-02-08T02:45:53.864411+00:00 heroku[webrtc.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-02-08T02:45:53.850099+00:00 heroku[webrtc.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-02-08T02:45:53.776642+00:00 app[webrtc.1]: module.js:540
2018-02-08T02:45:53.776677+00:00 app[webrtc.1]:
2018-02-08T02:45:53.776673+00:00 app[webrtc.1]:     throw err;
2018-02-08T02:45:53.776676+00:00 app[webrtc.1]:     ^
2018-02-08T02:45:53.776679+00:00 app[webrtc.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/signalmaster/server.js'
2018-02-08T02:45:53.776681+00:00 app[webrtc.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
2018-02-08T02:45:53.776683+00:00 app[webrtc.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
2018-02-08T02:45:53.776685+00:00 app[webrtc.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
2018-02-08T02:45:53.776686+00:00 app[webrtc.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
2018-02-08T02:45:53.776689+00:00 app[webrtc.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

And my start scripts look like this:

```
"build:production": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js",
"start": "node server/index.js",
"postinstall": "npm run build:production"
```

Comment: I found the problem. I had copied the signalmaster folder into my directory and hadn't included it in git.